# Can't run custom commands in Django 1.5.1

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've read the tutorial and did every step from it.

I've add management/commands folder to my project folder 
[image]

I've made python file for custom command

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
class Command(NoArgsCommand):

def handle(self, **options):
    print 'Hello world!'
```

After that I started my command

[image]

I've read all questions about this problem, but I didn't find any solution for me. And I don't understand where I can get

> _ *init* _ .py

files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `__init__.py` file in both management and commands directory.

You can create such a file using `touch __init__.py` in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

You don't "get" `__init__.py` files: you create empty ones. That's the reason your command is not found; you need those in both the `management` and the `commands` folders.

This is true for anything in Python; you always need an `__init__.py` to import a module within a subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this step for corrections;

1-create an empty file with name `__init__.py` in `management` directory.

2-create an empty file with name `__init__.py` in `commands` directory.

3-change your `add.py` like this:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print 'Hello world!'
```

Now you can run `management command` by:

```
./manage.py add
```